What is the distinction between the tags [network], [p2p], and [peers]?
We currently have network, p2p, and peers. It seems to me the tags largely overlap in the topics they collect, and I am considering to make p2p and peers synonyms of network.
network is described as:

This tag should be used for questions related to the Bitcoin network and communication between different nodes on the Internet.

peers is described as:

should be used for questions related to the peers of the bitcoin network

p2p does not have a description.
In the vicinity, we have the tags nodes, connection, peer-discovery, transaction-propagation, and relay among others.
Does someone see how the tags are distinct topics and why I should not? (Please upvote this question to support merging, reply to disagree.)

I could perhaps see a distinction between network and p2p, with network being for questions with a more big-picture network-architecture sort of scope, and p2p being for questions that are more specific (eg how individual peers talk to each).
This made me wonder if there is a gossip tag, and indeed there is... with only 1 (!) question using it.
Anyways, I think I agree with the merge, I'm just replying to point out that it might be useful to add gossip to the appropriate questions in tandem? That could allow the questions which are more specific to the P2P protocol to still have their own tag gossip, while catching all the wider network/P2P questions in the other tags (network, p2p, peers).
ie, I'd imagine that gossip would be a subset of network.

Yeah, I introduced [tag:gossip] late last year.

Your recommendation is not completely clear to me. Do I gather correctly that you would recommend merging [tag:peers] and [tag:p2p], but would keep that separate from [tag:network]? Additionally, you would like the tag [tag:gossip] to be applied to more questions?
